# \end{align} throws Package inputenc Error

Tags: align, subequations

Does somebody know why I get this error and how to fix it? There isn't even a "-" in the line "\end{align}"? Also, i have the exact same structure a few lines before and it doesn't throw an error..

```
\documentclass[11pt,
  paper=a4, 
  bibliography=totocnumbered,
    captions=tableheading,
    BCOR=10mm
]{scrreprt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 
 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes} % Context sensitive quotation.
\usepackage{amsmath} % Standard math.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subequations}{\def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}}%
{\def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}}{}{}
\usepackage{amsthm} % Math theorems.
\usepackage{amssymb} % More math symbols.
\usepackage{efbox}
\usepackage[sb,osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
 
\usepackage[section]{placeins} % Keep floats in the section they were defined in.
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Scientific table styling.
\usepackage{floatrow} % Option for keeping floats in the place they were defined in the code.
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks.
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=uos-red-full,citecolor=uos-red-full,filecolor=black,urlcolor=uos-red-full} % specs of hyperlinks
\usepackage[all]{nowidow} % Prevent widows and orphans.
\usepackage{xstring} % logic string operations
\usepackage{bbm} % \mathbb on numerals.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} % Pseudocode
\usepackage{scrhack} % Make warning go away.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % Subfigures with subcaptions.
\usepackage{authoraftertitle} % Make author, etc., available after \maketitle
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Placeholder text.
\usepackage[automake, nopostdot, nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries} % glossary for definitions and acronyms, without dot after entry and page reference 
\makeglossaries % Generate the glossary
\usepackage{uoslogo}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            bibstyle=apa,
            citestyle=apa,
            %maxnames=2,
            maxbibnames=99,
            uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url, final]
      \step[typesource=misc, typetarget=online]
    }
    \map{
      \step[typesource=misc, typetarget=patent, final]
      \step[fieldsource=institution, final]
      \step[fieldset=holder, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

%\linespread{1.5} % set line spacing
 
\usepackage{listings} % rendering program code
\lstset{% general command to set parameter(s)
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{grey},          % print whole listing small
    keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries\underbar,
    % underlined bold black keywords
    identifierstyle=,           % nothing happens
    commentstyle=\color{white}, % white comments
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,      % typewriter type for strings
    showstringspaces=false}     % no special string spaces


\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{1}{mathx}{"91}

\begin{document}

...
    
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    MAPE &= mean(|p_{t}|) \\
    MdAPE &= median(|p_{t}|) \\
    RMSPE &= \sqrt{mean(|p^{2}_{t}|)} \\
    RMdSPE & = \sqrt{median(|p^{2}_{t}|)} \\
    sMAPE &= mean(\frac{200 | Y_{t} − F_{t} |} {(Y_{t} + F_{t})})\\
    sMdAPE &= median(\frac{200 | Y_{t} − F_{t} |} {(Y_{t} + F_{t})})
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)

 
‪./main.tex, 404‬
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.404 \end{align}
                 
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Reading the error message, I guess you've copied/pasted some text: in the two last equations it seem you have a `–` instead of a `-` (in `$Y_{t} - F_{t}$`).

Comment: Oh wow, that's a stupid mistake. Thank you, that fixed it! I kept looking for a - in the line where I ended align.

Comment: Thank you for completing your code! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome :) // I'm overwhelmed by your preamble. I'd comment out almost all of those lines and reactivate packages etc. only when needed by your content. This way you'd fail and locate problems early, when e.g. order of packages might play a role.

Comment: @NBur is right. The error is reported at \end{align} due to the involved method used internally by amsmath structures. Hence reenter the minus above with your keyboard or add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}` on your preamble. The former preferabke to avoid possibke issues with Unicode 2212.